# How to add enter keyword action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add enter keyword action to below code but it's not working, anyone tells me whats wrong here?

```
$(".input").on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Check for full code - http://bagful.com.au/demo/asdasdsa/

Comment: is `input1` coming dynamically into your html?

Comment: Change `$(".input1")` to `$("#input")`, You have this as html `<input type="text" value="11" id="input">`

Comment: In the site you link to the `input` doesn't have a class of `input1`. It doesn't even have a class at all. It only has an `id`. Try `$('#input').on('keyup', ...`

Comment: sorry, my bad i just edit the question.  i added #input as per id input, but its not working

Comment: **`#input`** your still using `.input`. In jquery `#` is the id selector `.` is the class selector

Comment: i try both .input and #input but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#.input").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){

    }
});
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("input")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      alert("You got output");
    }
});


<input type="text" id="abc">
```

Comment: added, but not working.  can you plz copy entire code to test at your end. plz buddy

Comment: Just try the javascript..You got output

Comment: Now that's working one, Thanks   added my code to alert message - var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://example.com/a=add&pid="+inputvalue);

Answer (score 1):

This is simple look at your element:

```
<input type="text" value="11" id="input">
```

You're using a css class selector which is dot "."

```
$(".input1")
```

Actually, your html element has an id = input which leds you to use css id selector as:

```
$("#input1")
```

Comment: It would not work since the id of the object is not called `input1` but `input`

Comment: buddy, check clean one here - http://bagful.com.au/demo/google-apps/ still no luck

Comment: as he said above.  the id name must match the selector. I've missed the "1" after.

Comment: can you please try changing `$("#.input")` to `$("#input")`

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this code is helpful for you.

```
var a1= document.getElementById("textboxid"); 
a1.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        validate(e);
    }
});

function validate(e) {
    alert('Validated');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TazQ5/1/

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for reply buddy.  code working with -  User6667769